# django tastypie support for mashery iodocs?

Tags: django, api, tastypie, iodocs, mashery

[Mashery iodocs](https://github.com/mashery/iodocs) is a tool for documenting API. It needs two configuration json objects to run. It would be nice to have this objects generated automatically by tastypie. Tastypie can generate [json with schema](http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/interacting.html#inspecting-the-resource-s-schema), however it's incompatible with iodocs expectations. Any ideas of how to generate this configurtion automatically using tastypie?

Answer (score 0):

Presently, I do not believe there is a way to generate that kind of documentation from TastyPie directly.  However, I have found this project useful in creating interactive API documentation.

https://github.com/Hipo/Django-API-Playground

Answer (score 0):

One more project to generate documentation automatically - https://github.com/minism/django-tastypie-swagger

Though so far I haven't find anything convincing!